# how to rebind two or more radgrid's using javascript at once after any client postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three radgrid. I want to rebind all three radgrid at once the popup window is closed. but at a time it rebinds only one radgrid.
My code is here:

```
 $('.close-modal').click(function (e) {
                    $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeOut('fast');
                    var mymeeting = $find("<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                    var allmeeting = $find("<% =GridAllMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                    var activemeeting = $find("<% =GridActiveMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                    mymeeting.rebind();
                    allmeeting.rebind();
                    activemeeting.rebind();
                });*



 function rebind()
            {
                $find("<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
                $find("<% =GridAllMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
                $find("<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
            }*
```

Comment: do you want to rebind all the three radgrid's at the same time (like multi-threading) ?

Comment: In your code, you are using "GridMyMeeting.ClientID" twice, this will rebind the same grid twice. If you have 3 grids, use the id of 3rd grid

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to rebind all the grid's at the same time not simultaneously. Javascript does not have the concept of multi-threading but it can be achieved using [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) methods.

Since all grids need to be refreshed once, setTimeout will be enough. I have modified your code like below

```
$('.close-modal').click(function (e) {
       $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeOut('fast');
       //Storing Id of the grids in an array
       var gridId = ["<% = GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>", "<% = GridAllMeeting.ClientID %>", "<% = GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>"];               

       //Using setTimeout in for loop to rebind grid data at the same time
       for(var i=0; i<gridId.length; i++)
       {
           window.setTimeout(function(){
              var table = $find(gridId[i]).get_masterTableView();
              table.rebind();
           }, 10);     
       }                   
});
```

Above code will refresh your grids at an interval of 10 milliseconds. You can specify the interval value based on your requirement in the `setTimeout` function

Comment: while executing this code i got this error.Please help me

Comment: Its not binding all three grid, it binding only GridMyMeeting.Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: @karthika, Above code should work, please check the variable "gridId" contains the id of all the grids and the for loop executes three times

Comment: Its not entrying in to the loop,but while loading it taking the newly created item into grid but not bind it

Comment: hi....For loop executes well. It is retrieving all grid id.. But the grid is not binding.. only one grid is binding..

Comment: @karthikakarthi, modified my code again after referring http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-gridtableview-rebind.html

Comment: @Anand it is not working. Any one of the rebind works at a time.. Is there anyother way to achieve it in Javascript?

Comment: @Balaji, my guess is, grid that rebinds fast might have less data than the others or because of the grid settings like filtering, sorting,etc., JavaScript does not support threading as like server-side programming languages. But they support asynchronous execution of methods through setTimeout and setInterval methods.

Comment: @Anand anyway its not working because of this RADGRID features. finding alternate

Comment: @Balaji, An alternate possible solution would be, using a waiting pop-up on grid containers during the rebinding process and remove it once all the three grids have been rebounded. Client-side OnDataBound event of the grids can be used to identify whether rebinding completed on all the grids or not. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about radgrid but it seems you are finding same div (<% =GridMyMeeting.ClientID %>) in same view for all 3 instances. Thats why binding is added to single div.

Please change selector for selecting different div or change parent view.

Can you please share some JS fiddle code.